# How to bake Ambient Occlusion?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

How i can bake AO map? I followed a post and the final texture was black.I textured my model with image textures (PBR-diffuse,metalic,roughness and normal)

Comment: You can bake it from an other model. So if you want to make it from the texture, probably you have to create a very high resolution model and use a displace modifier on it, then bake it with selected to active.

Comment: Thanks!But if i do the same thing without the displace modifier is ok ?

Comment: No mention of which Blender version you are using, nor the source or destination render engines. From the standpoint of others who may look this up, it makes for a pretty useless post. Sorry to say...

Comment: Please, [have a read](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to bake the AO straight from your model you'll have to take the following steps:

1. Create a UV map for your object [image]
2. Create a new texture with the desired resolution [image]
3. Create a material with a texture node set to the newly created texture. This is necessary so that Cycles knows where to store the baked AO. [image]
4. Switch to Cycles render engine if you haven't already. Adjust samples and render settings as desired. [image]
5. Go to the *Bake* tab and select *Ambient Occlusion* in the *Bake Type* dropdown. [image]
6. Click *Bake* and save the texture when done. [image]